# Using MyFunction 2> to output to a text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an error log that only uses one text file. I currently am using `MainFunction 2> $Dest` but when it runs it overwrites the file. Full code example

```
$Dest = "C:\Error.txt"

Function MainFunction {
    if (!(test-path c:\temp\error)) {
            $Newfolder = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
            $Newfolder.createfolder("C:\Temp\error")
    }
}

MainFunction 2> $Dest
```

This should give an error if a Temp folder doesn't exist under `C:\`. Then record the error under `C:\Error.txt`. When the error is created it overwrites anything on the file already and I would like to keep adding errors to that file.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` redirection method will overwrite anything in the destination folder, this is by design.

Try changing it to the append redirection by using `>>` instead.

```
MainFunction 2>> $Dest
```

More details on this can be found at the [Docs.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) site.